# PHP input field instant update after typing in values

Tags: php, html

just trying to make a little calculator for myself in php and i wonder if its possible to make the answer instant update after i type in the values?

Thank you.

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];  
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];

if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {
    $answer = (($valuea * $valueb) * 10)*2; 
} else {
    $answer = ($valuea * $valueb) * 10; 
}


echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcrow">
    <td>Lenght:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calcrow2">
    <td>Width:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calcrow2">
    <td>2x test</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="check1"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>Answer</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($answer)?>"></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Ajax would be a start

Comment: Use javascript if you want it to execute client side.

Comment: @chris85 alright tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a thing called Jquery. 
Which can fetch current Values of your form inputs or any other elements from your webpage. Then you can then send that data to your php file where you can perform the calculation and return the result which can again be displayed wherever you want .

All of  this happens in real time. 
This is the way you could do it if you wanted to do it  in php

Else you could always go for plain JavaScript or a mixture of jquery + javascript, to avoid using php and ajax.

Comment: Jquery was made to handle easy dom manipulations and ajax request. It will be better if The OP used jquery to access and modify data or even send it via ajax to another php file for processing

Comment: Yeah, the OP mentioned in the question that he wants to do it with php.